# Как работает слово or в php?

Tags: php

Смотрю документацию php о функции `exit`. Натыкаюсь на такой пример:

```
$file = fopen($filename, 'r')
    or exit("Невозможно открыть файл ($filename)");
```

В самой документации на счёт `or` есть информация только как о логическом операторе. Я правильно понимаю, что этот `or` работает как конструкция `try-catch`? Если слева от `or` - false или функция, возвращающая false или ошибку, то выполняется код справа?

Comment: Да, приехало из Перла.. так себе синтаксис, но работает.

Comment: думаю да, по крайней мере я использую его так же)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже ответили, это действительно алиас `||`<sup>1</sup>.
Но это не аналог `try...catch`, так как последний ловит выброшенные исключения, а `||` выбирает из операндов.

Конструкция вида `$file = open(...) or die('Cannot open');` использует особенность вычисления оператора `OR`: если левый операнд равен `true` (или тому, что приводит к `true` в логическом контексте), то правый не вычисляется.
Поэтому либо файл открывается (функция вернёт `true`), либо вычисляется второй аргумент, в этом примере, останавливает скрипт с выводом ошибки.

Похожий вопрос на enSO: [Logical Operators, || or OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998309/6275986).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Приоритет токена `||` [выше](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php), чем `or`, спасибо [@tutankhamun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843251/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-or-%D0%B2-php#comment1353414_843265).</sup>

Comment: Это не совсем алиас. Оператор делает то же самое что и `||` но [приоритет операции](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php) ниже (пожалуй самый низкий)

Comment: @tutankhamun, Да, действительно, похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998309/6275986

Answer (score 1):

Это синоним `||` со всеми вытекающими в PHP. `Try-catch` ловить будет, если в исключении `true-false`, `0-1` и т.д.